# Using field tooltips - What's best practice?

Tags: bestpractice

What's the best practice for when/if to add field help text?  Should every field have help text or only the fields where the field label is not self-explanatory?

Note: This is a business question, not a technical one.  I know how to physically add help text.

Comment: There's been some close votes to this questions as it's quite subjective. Open questions which can't be answered with a "correct" anwer are discouraged and not a good fit for the stackexchange model (see help: [what not to ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), the salesforce success community is better suited for discution or subjective conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use help text as often as necessary, although you should avoid completely obvious help texts.

Bad Idea: Annual Revenue (?) [ The amount of revenue this account generates yearly. ]

Good Idea: ETUTCF (?) [ (pron. EE TUT CUF) The Estimated Time Until The Company Folds, expressed in a number of years, derived from various inputs such as stock health, product futures, etc. ]

In the first case, almost anyone that is in business understands annual revenue. It's a pretty clear term, and adding help text will likely only insult most people. On the other hand, ETUTCF is a term I made up just now, and I wouldn't expect anyone to know what the term is, even though it's *obvious to me* what it is (since I made it up).

As an exception, let's say that you wanted to clarify that Annual Revenue actually represents the average annual revenue only over the last 5 years, or that only includes hardware (not software) sales, etc. If you're modifying a standard term in some unusual way, include help text.

Use only as many help texts as you need, but do try to err on the side of having *too many* help texts instead of *too few*. I'd rather have a question mark next to every single field in the UI than to have a bunch of labels that I have to ask for their meaning and/or look them up every other week because I keep forgetting what some obscure term is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the field label is self explanatory for you but not for every user. There is no harm in adding Help Text to every field unless the help text and field label are almost same.